# Angular ui-routing and Asp.net Route not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-routing

I am fairly new to Angular, and I am trying to do an example with a parameter. The one without the parameter works fine, but the link with the parameter does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

The app and controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
        .when('/NewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/NewOrder',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).when('/ShowOrders/:orderID', {
            templateUrl: function (params) {return '/templates/ShowOrders?orderID=' + params.orderID; },
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/ShowOrders'
        });
    }
]);

myApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the add new order controller screen';
});

myApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope,$routeParams) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the show orders controller';
    $scope.order_id = $routeParams.orderID;
});
```

The Route.config file:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NewOrder",
            url: "templates/NewOrder",
            defaults: new { controller = "Templates", action = "AddOrder" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ShowOrders",
                url: "templates/ShowOrders/{orderID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Templates", action = "ShowOrders", orderID = "" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );

            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Defaults",
             url: "{*url}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

The html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
  </head>
 
  <body>
 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/NewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="/ShowOrders/123"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      
    @*<script src="app.js"></script>*@
      <script src="~/Scripts/myApp.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: all your server routes should map back to the angular entry point, not duplicate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you shouldn't be confuse between `angular-router` & `ui-router`, as currently you are using `angular-route`, thus you should use `ngRoute` module instead of `ui-router`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'/*, otherDependencies */]);
```

[**You can not have `params` inside your `templateUrl` function**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1524) while using `1.0.7` version of angular, instead you should have used latest version which have added support that you could have `$routeParmas` in your `$routerProvider` templateUrl function (Actually angular added this support since 1.1+).

Or if you wanted to stick with the older version for some reason then you could include the `$routeParams` as dependency in your `.config` function.

```
.when('/ShowOrders/:orderID', {
     templateUrl: '/templates/ShowOrders?orderID=' + $routeParams.orderID,
     controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
})
```

Comment: note also loading ui-router but using config for ngRoute

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the heads up man..I've edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** note - based on Charlietfl's comment below, this is the wrong answer. Per Stack overflow's preference I won't delete it, because having the wrong content can sometimes help guide users to an answer as well.

You'll have to excuse be because it's been a little over a year since doing angular + MVC4 ... I'm not even sure this deserves to be an "answer" over a comment

*BUT*

My recollection of angular routes is such that they only happen based on the things that happen AFTER the hash (barring a configuration setting)

Could you take a moment to test the route:

```
 /ShowOrders/123#/ShowOrders/123
```

and see if anything changes?  meantime I'll did through some old code to see if I can recall the nit-pickle-y bits of angular routing.

Comment: the `html5Mode` in angular routing removes the hash making the url's like virtual server directories

Comment: thanks! I didn't notice that - I've updated my wrong answer, but decided against deleting as someone may find value in your comment about `html5Mode` one day.